# Replacing a range in one G Sheet with same range from a different, but similar G Sheet template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goal:  to clear data from B3:I71 of the active spreadsheet, and replace it with data at B3:I71 of a separate template document I've created.  With this code I keep getting an error saying it can't find the specified range.

```
function menuItem2() {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Designates current sheet as destination document
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxx');  //Designates source document
  var A1Range = source.getRange("ACTIVITY LOG!B3:I71");   // Specifies a range in the source file, in A1 notation
  var cell = destination.getRange("B3");
  var SData = A1Range.getValues();   // gets the data values from inside this range
    destination.getRange(cell).setValues(SData);    // sets new values for all cells within target range at destination to the values of the source data
}
```

Big picture: I keep a weekly appointment log with random notes, times, dates, mileage, and various other metrics that gets all filled out and cluttered up by the end of the week and is quite tedious to reset for the start of the new week without deleting some of the data that I need to carry forward into the next week (most of which is saved outside of the specified range and thus would not be overwritten or deleted).
Code comments I've included may not be representative of what is actually happening here, just to the best of my limited understanding.  At what point do I stray from logical convention and can someone please get me back on track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function menuItem2() {
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName('destination sheet name');//add destination  sheet name
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxx');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName('ACTIVITY LOG');
  const sdt = ssh.getRange("B3:I71").getValues();
  dsh.getRange(3,2,sdt.length,sdt[0].length).setValues(sdt);//edit had row and column reversed sorry    
}
```